# Determinant of symmetric matrix with unit diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $A_2$ be a symmetric $2 \times 2$-matrix
$$
A_2
= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & a_{12}\\ 
a_{12} & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Clearly, we have
$$
\tag{1}
\det(A_2) = 1 - a_{12}^2.
$$

Let $A_3$ be a symmetric $3 \times 3$-matrix
$$
A_3
= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & a_{12} & a_{13}\\ 
a_{12} & 1 & a_{23} \\ 
a_{13} & a_{23} & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
We have
\begin{align}
\det(A_3) = 1 &- a_{12}^2 - a_{13}^2 - a_{23}^2 
\\
\tag{2}
&+ 2 a_{12}a_{13}a_{23}.
\end{align}

Let $A_4$ be a symmetric $4 \times 4$-matrix
$$
A_4
= 
\begin{pmatrix} 
1 & a_{12} & a_{13} & a_{14}\\ 
a_{12} & 1 & a_{23} & a_{24} \\ 
a_{13} & a_{23} & 1 & a_{34} \\
a_{14} & a_{24} & a_{34} & 1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
By using a general formula, we calculate
\begin{align}
\det(A_4) 
= 1 &- a_{12}^2 - a_{13}^2 - a_{14}^2 - a_{23}^2 - a_{24}^2 - a_{34}^2 
\\
&+ 2 a_{12}a_{13}a_{23} + 2 a_{12}a_{14}a_{24} + 2 a_{13}a_{14}a_{34} + 2a_{23}a_{24}a_{34}
\\
&-2a_{13}a_{14}a_{23}a_{24} - 2a_{12}a_{14}a_{23}a_{34} - 2a_{12}a_{13}a_{24}a_{34}
\\
\tag{3}
&+a_{14}a_{14} a_{23}a_{23} + a_{13}a_{13} a_{24}a_{24} + a_{12}a_{12} a_{34}a_{34}.
\end{align}

> What will be a structural generalization of $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$ to symmetric $n \times n$-matrix
>   $$
> A_4
> = 
> \begin{pmatrix} 
> 1 & a_{12} & \dots & a_{1n}\\ 
> a_{12} & 1 & \dots & a_{2n} \\ 
> \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
> a_{1n} & a_{2n} & \dots & 1
> \end{pmatrix}?
> $$

Comment: This isn't any easier than finding a formula for the determinant of an arbitrary symmetric matrix (indeed, you can always congrue your $A_n$ by a diagonal matrix to make the diagonal entries generic), for which I haven't seen any useful expressions.

Comment: May I ask how you encountered these matrices and the determinant, since I have  a similar problem? (see:  https://mathoverflow.net/questions/396276/simplex-invariants and  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4465952/is-there-a-name-for-this-algebraic-variety-and-how-would-you-visualize-it  )